# mysql query scope_identity error

Tags: c#, mysql

hey guys im having a really tough time trying to solve this error please help
im using c# with mysql connector and i wrote a query that goes something like this...

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(...); SELECT last_insert_id();
```

but i keep getting this error for some reason :(

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT scope_identity()' at line 1".
```

The part i dont get about this error is that i dont have `scope_identity()` written anywhere in my code.

I even removed the `SELECT last_insert_id();` part of my query but for some odd reason im still getting the same error.

[EDIT]
This generates the query perfectly but at the end it adds `scope_identity()` rather than `last_insert_id()`

```
public static MySqlCommand insert(string tableName, params object[] values)
    {
        string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES(";

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i == values.Count() - 1 && values[i] is string)
            {
                sqlQuery = sqlQuery + "'" + values[i] + "'";
            }
            else if (i == values.Count() - 1 && values[i] is int)
            {
                sqlQuery = sqlQuery + values[i];
            }
            else if (values[i] is string || values[i] is DateTime)
            {
                sqlQuery = sqlQuery + "'" + values[i] + "', ";
            }
            else if (values[i] is int)
            {
                sqlQuery = sqlQuery + values[i] + ", ";
            }
        }

        sqlQuery = sqlQuery + "); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); ";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery);

        return cmd;
    }
```

Comment: There's something fishy here...  can you post the actual query and the C# code you are using to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

string insert = "INSERT INTO employee VALUES(...)";

string select="SELECT last_insert_id()";

Comment: He should be able to do this in one query exactly as he has it (done it many times myself)

Comment: thnx for the reply MonTy but Eric is right. It should work like i have it, + like i said i even tried removing the select statement but it still gave the same error :(

Comment: got it working :P there was something wrong with the dll that i made. so i copy pasted the code from that to a new dll :P